# Fetch port number from elastic search supervisord file

Tags: python, elasticsearch

What is the best way to extract port number from the elastic search supervisord config file. Pasting config file content below for reference.

One way is I can open the file, read the content, and match 'port' against the regex. But I think regex matching can be prone to error hence looking for some other clean and smart solutions.

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/local/apps/supervisord.prod.log
pidfile=/local/apps/supervisord.prod.pid

[program:elasticsearch]
command=env JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk11" ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms15G -Xmx15G" /data/myapp/lib/elasticsearch-5.0.1/bin/elasticsearch -E http.host=%(ENV_HOSTNAME)s -E http.port=11132 -E path.data=/local/apps/myapp/elasticdata -E path.logs=/local/apps/myapp/elasticlogs -E http.max_content_length=800mb
autorestart=true
autostart=true
priority=10
redirect_stderr=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).
It handles the config files.